# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de las etiquetas en ggbarstats?

Tags: r

He realizado el siguiente gráfico de barras con ggbarstats y quisiera cambiar el color de los p valores y el color del tamaño muestral que aparece en azul para pasarlo a negro. ¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Pongo un ejemplo ficticio:

Adjunto tabla de contingencia de la que parto,

| Grado1 | Grado2 | Grado3 | Grado4 | Grado5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2900 | 392 | 932 | 1812 | 2854 |
| 522 | 421 | 574 | 917 | 1247 |
| 5678 | 8126 | 1171 | 1478 | 2040 |
| 3719 | 2975 | 2811 | 1704 | 2244 |

Código:

```
# transformo la tabla en tabla larga.

grados %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%            
  gather(Grados, valores, -rowname) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%                       
  mutate(valores = list(1:valores)) %>%  
  unnest(valores) %>%                   
  select(-valores) %>% 
  rename(Nivel = rowname) -> gradosLarga

ggbarstats(gradosLarga, x = Nivel, y = Grados)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesito cambiar el color azul de los resultados estadísticos (los p-valor) que están arriba de cada barra y pasarlo a color negro. E igual con la población muestral que aparece entre paréntesis abajo de cada barra. El gráfico está hecho utilizando ggbarstats.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que agregaras un ejemplo reproducible, incluso con datos falsos, pero con el código para reproducir el gráfico que estas haciendo. Saludos.

Comment: ¡Hola! No logro reproducir tu problema, al generar el gráfico, todo el texto me aparece en negro.  ¿Ya intentaste algo como `ggbarstats(gradosLarga, x = Nivel, y = Grados, ggtheme = theme_classic())`?

Comment: Hola Juan. Volví a reiniciar R y esta vez me apareció el texto en negro. Gracias por la ayuda.